# Live USB - Tails tries to boot but ends up booting into Kali Linux

Tags: boot, usb, kali-linux, live-usb, tails-os

I have a bootable USB drive with Tails and Kali Linux on it, among others. Kali boots fine.

However when I try to load Tails, it manages to get past the Tails loading screen but then the Kali logo appears and freezes, making me reboot. It comes to a screen that looks like this

[image: ss1]

However instead of "kali" it says "debian". Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: were you able to boot both of these from the same USB drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing an USB stick with another OS is not supported with Tails.
There is a high risk that any other partition, or even Tails itself gets damaged.